# Angular-Strap collapse plugin, opening more than one panel at the time (?)

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-strap

Hello folks this is the plugin http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##collapses

I am trying to use this plugin in my app but isn't doing what I want, I want to use it more dynamically, as you can see in the example on the web page, you can have only one panel open at the time, and I want to give to the users the option to have open as many panels as they want, and this is my html:

```
  <div class="panel-group" ng-model="panels.activePanel" bs-collapse>
    <div class="panel panel-default"
      ng-repeat="sport in sports" ng-show="sport.leagues.length">
      <div class="panel-heading"
        bs-collapse-toggle
        ng-click="addSportToLines(sport)">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a>
            {{::sport.name }}
          </a>
          <span class="pull-right badge">{{::sport.leagues.length }}</span>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-collapse" bs-collapse-target>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="list-group">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);"
              class="list-group-item panel-padding"
              ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues"
              ng-class="{active: league.active}"
              ng-click="addLeagueToLines(league)">{{:: league.name }}</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

is there a way to do it or I need to use another tool ?

Comment: Please remove any unnecessary code/markup to help the people whom you're asking help from. Must we weed through all the irrelevant tags, bootstrap classes, unrelated filters, etc... to find the source of your issue?

Comment: @NewDev what about now ?

Comment: hey look at this @SoluableNonagon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the angular-strap collapse control [here](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/collapse/collapse.js), you will notice this function inside the controller:

```
self.$setActive = $scope.$setActive = function(value) {
    if(!self.$options.disallowToggle) {
        self.$targets.$active = self.$targets.$active === value ? -1 : value;
    } else {
        self.$targets.$active = value;
    }
    self.$viewChangeListeners.forEach(function(fn) {
        fn();
    });
};
```

As you can see `$targets.$active` is a single value, meaning that the directive only accommodates one panel open at a time. To alter the functionality of the directive, you would have to fork it and make the necessary changes.

I would look at my answer to your similar question as a better approach. You do not need a library/plugin to get the result you are looking for. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611923/277697

Comment: I just answer to you, I really really need help.

Comment: Just to note that Angular-Strap supports multiple open panels since at least v.2.2 and probably earlier.  The relevant option is: `data-allow-multiple="true"`