# AngularJS - I need an accordion with the option to have multiple panels open at the time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this directive [JS Fiddle expample](http://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo/MTKp7/) with the option to open one panel at the time, I need to modify that behavior and give to the user the option to have multiple panels open.

Here below you will see the code which is the same on my [JS Fiddle Expamle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo/MTKp7/)

```
    directive("btstAccordion", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        template:
            "<div class='accordion' ng-transclude></div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            // give this element a unique id
            var id = element.attr("id");
            if (!id) {
                id = "btst-acc" + scope.$id;
                element.attr("id", id);
            }

            // set data-parent on accordion-toggle elements
            var arr = element.find(".accordion-toggle");
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                $(arr[i]).attr("data-parent", "#" + id);
                $(arr[i]).attr("href", "#" + id + "collapse" + i);
            }
            arr = element.find(".accordion-body");
            $(arr[0]).addClass("in"); // expand first pane
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                $(arr[i]).attr("id", id + "collapse" + i);
            }
        },
        controller: function () {}
    };
}).
directive('btstPane', function () {
    return {
        require: "^btstAccordion",
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: "@",
            category: "=",
            order: "="
        },
        template:
            "<div class='accordion-group' >" +
            "  <div class='accordion-heading'>" +
            "    <a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse'> {{category.name}} - </a>" +

            "  </div>" +
            "<div class='accordion-body collapse'>" +
            "  <div class='accordion-inner' ng-transclude></div>" +
            "  </div>" +
            "</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("title", function () {
                // NOTE: this requires jQuery (jQLite won't do html)
                var hdr = element.find(".accordion-toggle");
                hdr.html(scope.title);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the [`data-parent`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-options) attribute ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MTKp7/128/)):

```
//...
// set data-parent on accordion-toggle elements
var arr = element.find(".accordion-toggle");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //$(arr[i]).attr("data-parent", "#" + id);          <------- here
    $(arr[i]).attr("href", "#" + id + "collapse" + i);
}
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

This question IMO is a perfect example of not using angular well. I would suggest removing the entire directive, and jQuery, as they are unnecessary for a simple accordion (i.e. angular is perfect for this type of ui). Here is an updated version:

http://jsfiddle.net/MTKp7/131/

Now I have left it as verbose as possible so that you can make the choice about how you should abstract it (by using ng-repeat mixed with ng-include for example). I have also left the dependencies on the libraries so that the styles are preserved, but these are also not difficult to grab.

Here is the basic example of how you could create this functionality. The div structure and classes were only left to match the jQuery object.

```
<div class="accordion" ng-controller="AccordionCtrl">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggle('a')">test</a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body">
            <div class="accordion-inner" ng-show="show.a">
                <div>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life 
            accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute,
            non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt
            laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
            on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
            Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson 
            cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher
            vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw 
            denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of 
            them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And for toggling:

```
$scope.toggle = function(index) {
    $scope.show[index] = !$scope.show[index];
};
```

Comment: hey @Matt Way great, I was using an Angular-Strap plugin but nobody answer my question I had to remove that plugin, but anyways, can you check this for me please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610409/angular-strap-collapse-plugin-opening-more-than-one-panel-at-the-time

Comment: ok @Matt Way the issue here is that what I am doing is working with NodeJS(Sails) so I need to do it dynamically. I've been trying to put an example on Fiddle or Plunkr but I don't why I can't. If I put my code here are you able to help me?

Answer (score 1):

This?

http://jsfiddle.net/MTKp7/129/

Commented this line:

```
//$(arr[i]).attr("data-parent", "#" + id);
```